# Android language pack

Tags: android

I want to create language pack for android. How can I do this. If anyone knows how or where to find info about this topic please share your knowledge. I'd appreciate any pointers to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps start by looking at the [Locales](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) in Android?

**Edit**

Apparently it's not possible to make languages packs for Android without [contributing to the Android Open Source Project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4910048/31567). It seems a few people [have the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516829/how-to-create-language-pack-for-android) [as you](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15361/how-do-i-add-a-new-language). If you're interested in a specific Android app, that's dependent on the flexibility of the app itself. Sorry for the original, rather lacking, answer.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.  Can you elaborate?