# How to create language pack for Android?

Tags: android

I need to create language package for supporting a Regional language in my device, which is Currently not available in Android os. How can I create that ?

I don't know where to start, please point me to right direction.

Comment: If you are looking to change the language of the device as a whole, that is only possible by modifying the firmware. StackOverflow has limited ability to support such questions. You are better served researching your topic here: http://source.android.com

Comment: @CommonsWare  Thanks for the quick reply .Could you please point me to other resources , to dig more information on that

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949171/android-language-pack

Comment: See romain guy's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678169/how-to-create-a-custom-language-pack-for-android

Comment: http://blog.amr-gawish.com/39/arabic-language-in-android/