# How to create a custom language pack for android?

Tags: android, language-packs

For fun, I'd like to edit (or add a custom) language pack for my android phone.

I've read a lot about it using google but no real solution.

Is there any way to achieve this? maybe a way to get in to the language files google use and edit them, or add a new translation for the OS?

Any help would be appriciated :)

(additional info: I'm running android 2.2, HTC Legend)

Comment: Pieter, perhaps you'd have better luck on http://android.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know there was an android section. Am I supposed to delete this question and open it up there or is it cool if I leave two of the same question open at different sites?

Comment: I see here you got the answer rather than the android section :D

Comment: I also posted it in the android section but got no reply there: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5651/how-to-create-a-custom-language-pack-for-android

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such notion as "language packs." You can download the Android source (see http://source.android.com) and add/modify translations but you will have to submit your changes as an Open Source contribution to the Android Open Source Project.

The translations are done per application. For instance, all the translations for the Browser app are in packages/apps/Browser/res/values-LANGUAGECODE. The framework translations are in frameworks/core/res/res/values-LANGUAGECODE.

Comment: What a let down. I was hoping I could tweak my android this way. Well thanks anyway.

Comment: @Romain I am done with android ICS source code and compiled it.
How do I add/modify translations? I don't want everything as ready made food but I need just Guidance so that I can proceed further.