# Is it possible to add custom language by adding custom font in android devices?

Tags: android, custom-font, android-fonts, android-custom-keyboard

Is it possible to add my language(ladakhi) support in android because I don't see my language in android system by default so I wanted to add it manually. The way I am trying to do was by adding custom font (.tff) in my app and add to the android system.
But I am quite not sure whether it is possible or not ? If so please share me a resource or link where I can look up to.

**[Expected Result]**
Just like how we change android system language to hindi, kannada etc.I wanted to add my language support in android system.

Regards

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "new language" means here ? What is your end goal?

Comment: @AnkitGupta, thanks for the respond. I have update my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678169/how-to-create-a-custom-language-pack-for-android). The answer is you can't unless you download the android source and add a new language translation. For more you can @Romain Guy answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678169/how-to-create-a-custom-language-pack-for-android)